# need help to write correct egrep commands

Tags: regex, grep

I need help to find the correct way to write the commands

> 1. a command that copy lines in the file that containing question mark and redirect the result into another file.
> 2. a command that copy lines in the file that NOT containing digits and redirect the result into another file.
> 3. a command that copy lines in the file that NOT containing digits and redirect the result into another file using `>>` append redirection
> 4. produce the number of lines /orders for product XXX123 and store it in XXXcount
> 5. search a file for any lines that DO NOT contain 3 consecutive digits and append the result to another file

Comment: hi

I tried 

1- egrep ["?"] filename >newfile

2- egrep [0-9]* filename >newfile

3- egrep ^[?]$ filename >newfile

Comment: sorry i'm new at linux and I'm learning the egrep

Comment: Regarding 1, does `grep "?" filename >newfile` help?

Comment: No problem ;-) Do you want to use egrep *specifically* or will plain old `grep` also do the job for you?

Comment: no it doesnt work

I prefer to use (egrep)

Comment: Does `egrep "\?" filename >newfile` work for you? The question mark is a special character in regex processors like egrep.

Comment: for 1 & 2 It worked.... but I need the command to append the result to new file

Comment: Generally you can *append* to a file by using `>>` instead of `>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that works for me.

```
1. egrep "\?" filename >newfile
2. egrep -v "[0-9]" filename > newfile
3. egrep -v "[0-9]" filename >> newfile
5. egrep -v "[0-9]{3}" filename > newfile
```

For `4.`, you will need to use `wc -l` (counts lines:

```
egrep XXX123 filename | wc -l > XXXCount
```

As before, if you want to *append* instead of *overwrite*, use `>>` instead of `>`

Comment: you are great man

for 4

using egrep command and the appropriate egrep option produce the number of lines /orders for product XXX123 and store it in XXXcount using output redirection

Comment: So, you want to compute how many lines each of (1) (2) and (3) has, and multiply the results?

Comment: no, I just want to count how many lines containing XXX123 in that file and store the result in a new file

XXX123 has been mentioned many times in that file

Comment: @user3357669 Updated my answer accordingly